# Buying a Macbook pro retina 15", RAM or storage?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware-recommendation

I'm a web developer but I use a lot Photoshop and video editing software too and I'm about to buy a Macbook Pro retina 15" 2.4GHz.

I'm not sure if I should upgrade to 16GB of RAM or to 512GB of storage. I can only do one or the other due to budget.

What would you go for?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend that you upgrade the RAM.

This is because RAM is not user-replaceable and there is no way in the future to increase it. Storage, on the other hand, is more manageable via a USB 3, or Thunderbolt external harddrive. I have heard that the speed these peripherals is very reasonable.

I know from personal experience that 8GB of RAM feels a little weak when I have all my web development tools open as well as Photoshop. While more storage space is nice, my experience has been that 256 GB seems manageable.

Comment: I'd second this.  Only five years ago, 256GB of storage would have seemed plenty and you wouldn't have worried.  Not having enough RAM is going to hurt on a daily basis.

Comment: Definitely get the ram. As @denxd said it is not user upgradable. In addition to the thunderbolt and usb3 options that he mentioned, you can also upgrade the internal SSD later if you wish: http://eshop.macsales.com/shop/SSD/OWC/Aura_Pro_Retina_2012/